# Vision transformer for Image as output

Tags: transformer-model

Normally vision transformer is used for classification. Can it be used for the image where the output is image? If some repository is there, please share the link.

I want to analyze the architecture last layers which result the image as output but most of the architecture is related to classification.

Answer (score 0):

Vision Transformers (ViTs) are indeed flexible enough to be used for image output tasks, not just classification. The reason lies in their ability to treat **parts of an image as a sequence**, similar to words in a sentence, which allows for complex feature relationships and reconstruction of images. My paper, "Efficient Scopeformer," explores a hybrid CNN-ViT architecture that efficiently extracts features for medical imaging, hinting at this possibility (check the modules I used). Additionally, my YouTube video titled "Vision Transformer inside a UNet architecture" explains how ViTs can integrate within a UNet for tasks like segmentation, which maps features to features, and so still you can use it for features to features, image to features or features to images.
Here's the link to my paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/10201867
And the video explaining ViTs in UNet:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKBJITQ8xJY
OTher videos in my channel explains the dimensions of input output of ViTs and so you can understand how flexible they are.